# Spring Boot @Scheduled method create instance of @Scope(request)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scope, spring-scheduled

I'm having a problem with spring scopes. I'm sure that my solution isn't the most optimal but I don't know a better way to do that. Do you have any suggestions?

There is my problem:

**What I need:**

I'm trying to perform the same operation than a `@RESTController` mapped method, but periodically in the background, without any user http/s call.

**What I have:**

Currently, I have some `@Service` classes scoped as `@Scope(REQUEST)`, that `@RestController` is calling from the http/s call.

**What I'm trying**

I have created a new `@Component` class with an `@Scheduled` method that's trying to call the `@Service` which what are scoped as `@Scope(REQUEST)`.

**My problem:**

The `@Scheduled` method cannot use the `REQUEST` scoped `@Service` because they aren't on a request scope, and it's too hard to change all related services to that operation.

Thank you!

Comment: All the logic for the request should be in a service method.... so have your scheduled task call the service method...

Comment: @RobOhRob the service is request scoped

Comment: Why is the service even request scoped? Is there state in the service you need to keep?

Comment: I am having the same problem and can't change my code, because I connect to a FTP server and have to disconnect from it, forcing me to have a request scoped bean and now I've been asked to enable the feature to also be run in a scheduled way, did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

So that would mean an instance of the service is created for a request, but if there is no request, there is no bean instance. Couldn't you create a seperate bean instance for your scheduled job?

Basically remove the @Service from your service class and create a Configuration file

```
@Configuration
class FooServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    FooService requestFooService(){
        return new FooService()
    }

    @Bean
    FooService scheduledFooService(){
        return new FooService()
    }
}
```

And then autowire the requestFooService from where-ever it is used in your request flow and autowire the scheduledFooService from your scheduled job.

Comment: It was one of my alternatives, but that means changing a lot of services. So, for that reason, I'm looking for another alternative, if possible.

PD: Thank you! <3

Comment: I dont think there is another alternative, other than removing the request scope from the service. I can't imagine a situation that you would truly need that scope in so many services. Do you really need a separate instance of all these services for each request? Will they all have thread safety issues otherwise? If not? If it is just a regular stateless service, just remove the request scope and turn it into a normal singleton bean.

Comment: Yep, I think so.

Comment: @NurioFernández, here's my use case: I connect to a FTP server and have to disconnect from it, forcing me to have a request scoped bean and now I've been asked to enable the feature to also be run in a scheduled way, do you see a way out?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi check out `context.getBean()` with scope prototype